# How to boost perf on Angular 4 project

Tags: apache, angular, typescript

I am working on a project using Angular 4 for the frond-end and phph for the back-end with an Apache server using ubuntu 16.04 LTS where we  setup Node JS to make's actually works Angular. So I have two questions in one, how do do to make run Angular 4 without Node JS? Are all our perf issues comming from that (Node JS on apache?) or is it my code who's make run the apps very slow? For exemple, when I check the access log servor from apache using cat /dev/null >access_log I see like 30 requests just to run the first page...how could I optimise that?

See my plunker link here (not all the code is here but he give you an idea of the construction) [Mypluker][1]

```
   [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/4CUPwqehwkiHNnFd1NtU?p=catalogue
```

Comment: What toolchain do you use? SystemJS/JSPM, Webpack/npm, Rollup/npm?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not sure, I start from a quick start package and I change nothing I the package.json

Comment: You will need to learn the specifics of configuring whichever build tool it is in order to optimize the number of requests. It's also possibly you are downloading a number of assets from CDNs so I would start by checking your index.html file for script tags and links

Comment: @AluanHaddad I only have one cdn for JQuery but after npm start when I go in the log access from apache I can see 32 requests !!!

Comment: If you add the list of requests to your question, someone might be able to help.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes you right I ll addict it !

Answer (score 0):

The quickstart seed from angular.io ils not expected to be used for production. It's just an example of how you can quickly start developement.
For instance the quickstart do typescript transpilation inside the browser. You should avoid this kind of things.

One of the easiest solution for dev and production build is to use [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io).

With a production build you don't need nodejs only a webserver that can serve static files.

Comment: ahright many many thanks this is very helpful..  I tried already to use angular cli but since I'am have my pc running on Linux (Xubuntu distrib) cli doesn't work anymore... since I had bublishBehavior method on my Observable it works faster...but anyway I'll have to move to Apache without node very soon so I'm very interested to know how works without node npm